# Accessing ejb in ear from war via local interface

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, weblogic12c

Is it possible to access ejb that resides inside ear file, from a war using local interface?
Both deployed under same app server.

The ejb:

```
@Stateless(name="FirstDemoEJB",mappedName = "FirstDemoEJB/Local")
public class FirstSessionBean implements FirstSessionBeanRemote, FirstSessionBeanLocal {
}
```

Now, in test servlet (war):

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();          
Object ob = context.lookup("java:comp/env/FirstDemoEJB/Local");
```

Fails on:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up
>   comp/env/FirstDemoEJB/Local in /app/webapp/FirstWebEJBTest/12292093.;

But remote lookup works fine:

```
Object ob  = context.lookup("FirstDemoEJB/Local#org.weblogic.FirstSessionBeanRemote");
```

Comment: In WebLogic (as far as I remember), you can use the `RemoteInterface` there. The container checks if it's really a `LocalInterface` and uses it as one when possible. The reverse isn't allowed by the specification.

Comment: I know that JBoss AS7 had some trouble with this. Just mentioning it to show that it might be a problem on their end.

Answer (score 1):

You should use container dependency injection to access the ejb from the servlet. Most likely, the problem is that you have the jndi lookup path incorrect. Using the container dependency injection relieves you of knowing the jndi naming scheme.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB(mappedName = "FirstDemoEJB/Local")
    private FirstSessionBeanLocal firstSessionBeanLocal;
}
```

Comment: Just adding the above annotation?

Comment: i think  you might also need an empty beans.xml file in the meta-inf folder, maybe not.  for more info please see: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/cdi-javaee-bien-225152.html

Comment: Just adding ````@EJB ```` annotation works.